# React Native DateTimePickerModal from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker" Not letting me add 2 DateTime picker in one component

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

I need to add 2 DateTimePicker to my component in my React-native app. But only one work even if i add 2. I can open each datetimepicker but only one value change that is the top one. So can select bottom one and will only change the top value.  See the code below

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import DateTimePickerModal from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';
import moment from 'moment';

const Example = () => {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState();
  const [selectedDate1, setSelectedDate1] = useState();
  const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisibility] = useState(false);

  const showDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(true);
  };

  const hideDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(false);
  };

  const handleConfirm = (date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
    hideDatePicker();
  };

   const handleConfirm1 = (date) => {
    setSelectedDate1(date);
    hideDatePicker();
  };
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{`Date:  ${selectedDate? moment(selectedDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY"):"Please select date"}`}</Text>
      <Button title="Show Date Picker" onPress={showDatePicker} />
      <DateTimePickerModal
        isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
        mode="date"
        onConfirm={handleConfirm}
        onCancel={hideDatePicker}
      />
       <Text>{`Date:  ${selectedDate1? moment(selectedDate1).format("MM/DD/YYYY"):"Please select date"}`}</Text>
      <Button title="Show Date Picker" onPress={showDatePicker} />
      
      <DateTimePickerModal
        isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
        mode="date"
        onConfirm={handleConfirm1}
        onCancel={hideDatePicker}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

So I am wondering if it is even possible to add 2 DateTimePicker into one component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is only 1 state handling the opening of the pickers which is causing the first to open each time

```
const [isDatePickerVisibleOne, setDatePickerVisibilityOne] = useState(false)
const [isDatePickerVisibleTwo, setDatePickerVisibilityTwo] = useState(false)
```